# ¿Como se hace una query que suma todo en Realm.io en Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, realm

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta que me entregue la suma total del `percent` asociada a una `id_character`, aquí están mis clases

Tengo una clase así:

```
class DBCharacter: Object
{
    dynamic var id_character:String = ""
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? { return "id_character" }
}
```

Tengo otra clase:

```
class DBItem: Object
{
    dynamic var id_item:String = ""
    dynamic var id_character:String = ""
    dynamic var percent:Float = 0
}
```

Lo hago de esta manera, pero me tira error:

```
let filterItems  = NSPredicate(format: "id_character = %@",  self.id_character)
let totalPercent = realm.objects(DBItem.self)
                                .filter(filterItems)
                                .sum(ofProperty: "percent")
```

El error que lanza es:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer con un `FOR` pero la idea es hacerla solo con `SQL`

```
let filterItems  = NSPredicate(format: "id_character = %@",  self.id_character)
let items = realm.objects(DBItem.self).filter(filterItems)

var totalPercent:Float = 0
var nItems = 0
for item in items
{
    totalPercent = totalPercent + item.percent
    nItems = nItems + 1
}

let dbCharacter = realm.object(ofType: DBCharacter.self, forPrimaryKey: self.id_character)
try! realm.write
{
    dbCharacter?.knowledge = totalPercent/Float(nItems)
}
```